# enumerated types not overwriting even though cardinality/one

Tags: clojure, enums, datomic

In writing a rating system, I want people to be able to rate posts, but I only want there to be one rating per user.

So in my schema I have something like

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db -1] 
 :db/ident :rating/value
 :db/valueType :db.type/ref
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one  <<thinking this serves a purpose
 :db/doc "rating applied to this particular post"
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -2] 
 :db/ident :rating.value/verypositive}

{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -3]
 :db/ident :rating.value/positive}

{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -4]
 :db/ident :rating.value/needswork}
```

I only want there to be accessible one rating per email at any time, but I am a little stumped.

When I submit several ratings to a post

```
>(add-rating-to-post 1759 "so@gm.co" "verypositive")
>(add-rating-to-post 1759 "so@gm.co" "needswork")
>(add-rating-to-post 1759 "so@gm.co" "positive")
>(add-rating-to-post 1759 "so@gm.co" "verypositive")
```

The transaction works fine, but when I query for the ratings attached to a particular post-eid I get something like

```
({:bid 1759,
  :rating :rating.value/verypositive
  :email "sova@web"}
 {:bid 1759,
  :rating :rating.value/positive,
  :email "sova@web"}
 {:bid 1759,
  :rating :rating.value/needswork,
  :email "sova@web"})
```

Really, all I want is the latest one, so a returned list of all the ratings a user submitted where I can take (last x) would be great.

...but it will populate until there is one of each of the enumerated types, and then disregard additions.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve the behavior I'm striving for?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your schema is essentially saying at the moment is that you are allowed exactly one value **per rating.value**

I would suggest that the 'single rating per user' should not be a schema constraint but instead is a domain level problem - The appropriate way of implementing this would be to allow *multiple ratings* per post per user and then write a transactor function that would check if a user have rated a post before and either **deny** rating again, or **retract** the old rating (depending on what behaviour you want).

You also would want to treat the rating itself as an entity, if you're not doing that already. So that you have `:rating/post :ref`, `:rating/value :ref` and `:rating/email` attributes and create a new entity for every rating.

Comment: Seems like the best way to achieve what I want is through retracting :rating/values that already are, so that there's only one at a time.  Thanks for taking the time to read through my  question.  I guess enumerated types have other potential uses, this not really being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is correct. Your use of idents for enumeration is correct.

Instead of creating a new rating entity every time, use a query to check whether there is one already with the rated `:bid` and the rating users `:email`. If so, transact the new `:rating` attribute with a `:db/add` assertion (don't worry about retractions, they are created implicitly for `:cardinality/one` attributes). If not, create one like you are already doing.

If you need to do it atomically, e. g. to avoid the creation of two rating entities by the same user on one article in a race condition, you the need  all that to be done within the transactor by writing and using a [database function.](http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html)

If you need to see all the ratings a user has given, use a feature like [history database](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/history) to query for how the `:rating` value of an entity has changed over time.